# IMacros DATASOURCE from external source

Tags: javascript, php, csv, imacros

I have a script that extracts the data from a (local) CSV file and use it to fill some forms.

The problem I face is that I want to generate this CSV file on my VPS (with PHP), so I replaced:

```
SET !DATASOURCE data.csv
```

with

```
SET !DATASOURCE http://www.example.com/data.csv
```

Unfortunately, it seems that iMacros doesn't support an online datasource.
Is there a way I could easily bypass this restriction?
Maybe by combining my macro with JavaScript?

I get the following error message:

```
NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH: Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath], line: 5 (Error code: -1001)
```

Comment: Make an imacros code that downloads that file from your VPS on hard drive.

Comment: That's actually a great idea! I'm on it.